# how can we display only the timezone in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, timezone

how can we display only the timezone in AMPscript using now(). 
I tried using `%%=Format(Now(),'zzzz')=%%` but its not displaying the timeZone instead it's displaying `-06:00`.

Answer (score 4):

Reviewing the [AMPscript guide](https://ampscript.guide/date-and-time-functions/), there seems to be no formatting option to display the timezone, only the TZ offset.

Comment: Is this still valid? There's no way to add a timezone like 3 letters  on the time?